# rsync ssh recursive dry run error / no rsync on server

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

looking to use rsync to transfer directory from remote to local recursivly with a dry-run.
So far from [rync man pages](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) I settle on this:

```
rsync -rnvh user@server.com:/directory /local_directory/
```

and I get this

```
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127)
```

do I have to use this:

```
scp -rv user@server.com:/directory /local_directory/
```

(Which works perfectly fine for my one-time limited case) I'd rather get rsync running.

I've tried installing rsync on server without success. My access is quite limited on the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `-e ssh` (unless you're using a really really ancient version of rsync) - ssh is the default.

For dry run:

```
rsync -avn user@server.com:/directory/ /local_directory/
```

For actual sync:

```
rsync -av user@server.com:/directory/ /local_directory/
```

Also note the trailing `/`s - otherwise you can end up with `/local_directory/local_directory` etc.